# FastAI to PyTorch conversion

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I have been taking the FastAI course. And if anyone else has taken this course they know that they use their own python library called `fastai` that is a wrapper for PyTorch functions. This is effective for having time to explain theory, but I am wondering how these same methods would be implemented directly from PyTorch. Has anyone seen any blog posts or anything where someone has rewritten some fastai lessons in base PyTorch commands? I found one here: https://medium.com/@tomgrek/wtf-is-going-on-with-fast-ai-db59741b5da2 but that is all I could find, and I'm not even sure which lesson this converts.  Thanks!

Comment: Have not seen it, but it is totally possible. I was skimming the library this weekend for ideas, and I agree that in most cases it takes away from the pytorch visibility. Is there a particular lesson you are interested in? all of them are very known things, so for example on lesson 1, it is cats v dogs with a resnet34. github pytorch cats v dogs gets you to some existing implementations, and you can see whats going on with the training loop: https://github.com/desimone/pytorch-cat-vs-dogs/blob/master/main.py .

Comment: @PavelSavine Yes, that is helpful. Ideally I would like to see the exact implementation that Prof Jeremy uses in FastAI but rewritten in PyTorch so that I can kind of translate it in my head (if that makes sense). Lesson 4 is particularly of interest to me on structured data. Prof uses classes like: `ColumnarModelData` and a method called `fit` in the fastai library, which have no documentation and when I read the pytorch code it's pretty much foreign to me. I may just have to try to rewrite these things myself with a lot of SO help.